# Error Number: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, join

I am getting below mysql database error

```
Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'option, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT year_question_map.year) AS years, GROUP_CONCAT(DIS' at line 1

SELECT `questions`.*, `question_level`.*, `question_answer`.*, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT question_option.question_option SEPARATOR '__') AS option, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT year_question_map.year) AS years, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT exams.exam_name) AS exams FROM `questions` LEFT JOIN `question_option` ON `question_option`.`question_id` = `questions`.`qid` LEFT JOIN `question_level` ON `question_level`.`level_id` = `questions`.`level_id` LEFT JOIN `question_answer` ON `question_answer`.`question_id` = `questions`.`qid` LEFT JOIN `year_question_map` ON `year_question_map`.`question_id` = `questions`.`qid` LEFT JOIN `exams` ON `exams`.`exam_id` = `year_question_map`.`exam_id` WHERE `questions`.`topic_id` = '1' GROUP BY `questions`.`qid` ORDER BY `qid` ASC
```

I am Using Codeigniter and here is my sql query in my model

```
        $this->db->select("questions.*,question_level.*,question_answer.*,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT question_option.question_option SEPARATOR '__') AS option,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT year_question_map.year) AS years,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT exams.exam_name) AS exams");
    $this->db->from('questions');
    $this->db->join('question_option','question_option.question_id = questions.qid','left');
    $this->db->join('question_level','question_level.level_id = questions.level_id','left');
    $this->db->join('question_answer','question_answer.question_id = questions.qid','left');
    $this->db->join('year_question_map','year_question_map.question_id = questions.qid','left');
    $this->db->join('exams','exams.exam_id = year_question_map.exam_id','left');    
    $this->db->where('questions.topic_id',$topicID);
    $this->db->group_by('questions.qid');
    $this->db->order_by('qid','ASC');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
    return $query->result();
} else {
      return FALSE;
  }
```

Comment: `question_option.question_option` ?? or `question_option.OPTIONNAME` ??

Comment: question_option.question_option NOT question_option.OPTIONNAME

Comment: maybe error because of same table and same column name..

Comment: I have checked it by using different name but it giving the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using **[MYSQL Reserve](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html)** Word in your query:

```
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT question_option.question_option SEPARATOR '__') AS OPTION,
```

Note that OPTION is a reserve word you must need to use backtick or change it with other name.

*This should be:*

```
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT question_option.question_option SEPARATOR '__') AS `OPTION`,
```

*For reference, you can check the list of Reserve words here:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html*

**(R)** with any word in given below reference indicates this is a reserve word.

Comment: Thanks @devpro for pointing out the error & for the reference now it working like charm. Thanks once again